# Loading an .erb file in shakapacker

Tags: ruby-on-rails-6, webpacker, shakapacker

How can I load a file like?

```
require('../src/active_admin/admin/menu.coffee.erb');
```

if I'm using Shakapacker? (new webpacker)

Answer (score 1):

Answer:

```
yarn add -D rails-erb-loader
```